# numpy select members with a certain shifted window

Tags: python, numpy

I want to extract some members from many large numpy arrays. A simple example is

```py
A = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
       [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35]])
```

I want to extract the members in a shifted windows in each row with minimum stride 2 and maximum stride 4. For example, in the first row, I would like to have

```
[2,  3,  4]  # A[i,i+2:i+4+1] where i == 0
```

In the second row, I want to have

```
[9, 10, 11]  # A[i,i+2:i+4+1] where i == 1
```

In the third row, I want to have

```
[16, 17, 0]
```

```
[[2, 3,  4],
[9, 10, 11],
[16 17, 0],
[23, 0, 0]]
```

I want to know efficient ways to do this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can extract values in an array by providing a list of indices for each dimension. For example, if you want the second diagonal, you can use arr[np.arange(0, len(arr)-1), np.arange(1, len(arr))]

For your example, I would do smth like what's in the code below. although, I did not account for different strides. If you want to account for strides, you can change the behaviour of the index list creation. If you struggle with adding the stride functionality, comment and I'll edit this answer.

```
import numpy as np

def slide(arr, window_len = 3, start = 0):
    # pad array to get zeros out of bounds
    arr_padded = np.zeros((arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1]+window_len-1))
    arr_padded[:arr.shape[0], :arr.shape[1]] = arr
    # compute the number of window moves
    repeats = min(arr.shape[0], arr.shape[1]-start)
    # create index lists
    idx0 = np.arange(repeats).repeat(window_len)
    idx1 = np.concatenate(
        [np.arange(start+i, start+i+window_len)
        for i in range(repeats)])
    return arr_padded[idx0, idx1].reshape(-1, window_len)



A = np.arange(36).reshape(6,6)

print(f'A =\n{A}')
print(f'B =\n{slide(A, start = 2)}')
```

output:

```
A =
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
B =
[[ 2.  3.  4.]
 [ 9. 10. 11.]
 [16. 17.  0.]
 [23.  0.  0.]]
```